# Can't get elements to stack

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

CSS isn't necessarily my strong suit but I have no idea why I can't get these two elements to stack? I set the parent position to `relative` and the child to `absolute` I also give the child a higher `z-index` but just can't get it to work. The `<Icon />` is always offset to the right.

[image]

Code

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const propTypes = {
  iconName: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string,
};

const defaultProps = {
  iconName: 'add_box',
  color: '#27B678',
};

const MaterialIcon = props => (
  <i className={`material-icons ${props.className}`}>
    {props.iconName.replace(/['"]+/g, '')}
  </i>
);

const Icon = styled(MaterialIcon)`
  color: ${props => props.color.replace(/['"]+/g, '')};
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
`;

const Divider = props => (
  <div
    className="mx2"
    style={{ position: 'relative', border: '1px solid #ececec' }}
  >
    <Icon
      iconName={props.iconName}
      color={props.color}
    />
  </div>
);

Divider.propTypes = propTypes;

Divider.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Divider;
```

Comment: if the parent has a relative position, using absolute on any other element within the parent, you don't need z-index, you just use top, left, right, bottom to position the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `top` and `left` to position the icon over the divider. You should give `left` a negative value equal to half the width of the icon so that it is centered over the divider. For instance, if the icon width is 50px, your `Icon` style should look like this:

```
const Icon = styled(MaterialIcon)`
  color: ${props => props.color.replace(/['"]+/g, '')};
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10%;
  left: -25px;
`;
```

Make sure to also give your divider a `z-index` of 0 so that the Icon appears on top of it.